# Baked normal looks pixelated

Tags: normals, sculpting

I have two models one low poly and one high poly. The high poly is one that I have been sculpting on and I used that one to bake a normal, but for some reason when I use the normal on the low poly model it looks pixely.Any idea why?

This is the low poly model with the normal applied

[image: Low poly]

[image]

This is the high poly

Comment: That looks like compression artifacts to me, possibly because the normal map was saved as jpeg.

Comment: could you please pack the image and share your file?

Comment: Thank you @rjg that was the problem.